# Julian Date Conversion

Tags: java, julian-date

```
Sample Julian Dates:
2009218
2009225
2009243
```

How do I convert them into a regular date?

I tried converting them using [online converter](http://www.csgnetwork.com/julianmodifdateconv.html) and I got-

12-13-7359 for 2009225!! Makes no sense!

Comment: your examples aren't julian dates. an julian date is the number of days since January 1, 4713 BC - for example 2.451.545 for 2000-01-01. (if 2009225 is a julian date like you want it to be, the online converter is right)

Comment: I thought so but I have no idea what kind of dates are those! Can't even ask.

Comment: it isn't clear to me what you're trying to convert from: Julian Calendar dates? Or Modified Julian _Days_ (astronomical data), as in your link? If those dates start with a year, there is room for ambiguity (is 2009111 January 11 or November 1?).

Comment: I wish I could ask the client and answer your question.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that they are of the format "YYYYDDD" - the DDDth day of year YYYY. However, if you want to make sure it's done right *you have to ask the source of the dates*, or at the very least, have a sufficient amount of examples (both the encoded date and the corresponding actual date) to be able to determine the meaning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net) library and do something like this:

```
String dateStr = "2009218";
MutableDateTime mdt = new MutableDateTime();
mdt.setYear(Integer.parseInt(dateStr.subString(0,3)));
mdt.setDayOfYear(Integer.parseInt(dateStr.subString(4)));
Date parsedDate  = mdt.toDate();
```

Using the Java API:

```
String dateStr = "2009218";
Calendar cal  = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,Integer.parseInt(dateStr.subString(0,3)));
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,Integer.parseInt(dateStr.subString(4)));
Date parsedDate  = cal.getTime();
```

---- EDIT ----
Thanks for Alex for providing the best answer:

```
Date myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyD").parse("2009218")
```

Comment: MutableDateTime will figure out the month, since it knows the year and day of year.

Comment: Is there no way I can use the Java API to do that?

Comment: An upvote and/or marking my answer as correct would be appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry - my bad. :)) Note: You might want to edit a little further since set doesn't have (int, long) methods. Might want to change them to integer.

Comment: Use the built in date parsers!

Comment: Elaboration on that would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Alex is right. That's the best answer, you could do `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyD").parse("2009218")` to get your Date object

Answer (score 3):

Another format is CYYDDDD I wrote this function in Java

```
public static int convertToJulian(Date date){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    String syear = String.format("%04d",year).substring(2);
    int century = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(((year / 100)+1)).substring(1));
    int julian = Integer.parseInt(String.format("%d%s%03d",century,syear,calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)));
    return julian;
}
```