# Julian date to regular date conversion

Tags: java, date, julian-date

How do i convert a julian date 2456606 which stands for Nov 18 2013 to the string format 18/11/2013 using java APIs? I tried executing the below code but it is not giving me the right answer. Any corrections to the below code are welcome

```
    String j = "2456606";
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyD").parse(j);
    String g = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(date);
    System.out.println(g);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Julian Date Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036761/julian-date-conversion)

Comment: @keaplogik: I don't find solution to my question there..I find that SimpleDateFormat class helps me only to parse the date number string  in the given pattern and not help me convert between julian and calender dates..

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I use Julian Day Numbers with the Java Calendar API?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14988459/642706)

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Julian date for Nov 18 2013 is `"2013322"`.  The number you used, `"2456606"`, would be the 606th day of 2456, which is Aug 28, 2457.

You might also have intended to use a different date format than `"yyyyD"` for your input.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for information on possible codes.

**Edit**

The value that you used for the Julian date is the number of days since January 1, 4713 BCE.  To get the Julian date using that system, you'll need to do something like the following:

```
String j = "2456606";
int day = Integer.parseInt(j) - x; // x == Jan 1, 1970 on the Gregorian
j = Integer.toString(day);
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("D").parse(j);
String g = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(date);
System.out.println(g);
```

Where `x` is the Julian day corresponding to Jan 1, 1970 on the Gregorian calendar, i.e., the number of days elapsed between January 1, 4713 BCE and Jan 1, 1970.

Comment: Actually I just find the julian date to be 2456606 for nov 18 in the converter link mentioned below http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/JulianDate.php.. Also i wasn't aware of the fact that the date get parsed in the form of the pattern mentioned in the constructor and thanks for pointing it out.. It would be helpful if u cd provide me a solution with converting my calender date to the julian date that the converter returns..

Comment: @learner See my edit.  Also note that the link you use is giving you "real" Julian dates, not dates on the Gregorian calendar.  The Julian Nov 18 2013 will be sometime in December this year.

Comment: Could you elaborate, how you derived the value for `x`? Because I tried to convert the `01.01.1970` into a Julian date, which gives me `2440587.5`, so not an int. I changed the ints in your example to doubles, but somehow now my dates are several hours to days off.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.MIN.with ( 
    java.time.temporal.JulianFields.MODIFIED_JULIAN_DAY , 
    2_456_606L 
)
```

> 2013-11-09

Other direction, from modern date to Julian Day.

```
 LocalDate.of( 2013 , 11 , 9 )
          .getLong ( java.time.temporal.JulianFields.JULIAN_DAY )
```

> 2456606

## Details

Firstly, your comment:

> the julian date to be 2456606 for nov 18 in the converter link mentioned below aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/JulianDate.php

…is incorrect. That web site returns November 9, 2013 for 2456606.

[image: Screen shot of US Naval Observatory reporting 2013-11-09 as the modern date for a Julian Day of 2456606]

Your [Navy web site](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/JulianDate.php) defines *Julian Date* as a count of days since  January 1, 4713 BC mapped to “Universal Time”. I assume they mean [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) and the modern ISO 8601 calendar system. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day).

The java.time classes built into Java make this easy.

```
long input = 2_456_606L;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.MIN.with ( java.time.temporal.JulianFields.JULIAN_DAY , input );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " is: " + ld );
```

> input: 2456606 is: 2013-11-09

For more discussion, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38278281/642706) on a duplicate Question.

Going the other direction, converting a modern date to a Julian Day.

```
long output = ld.getLong ( java.time.temporal.JulianFields.JULIAN_DAY );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
If you have 7 digit julian date then you can use the following to convert it to Gergorian date.
```

The longJuliandate is your input and it'd return a String, which you can format for Date. You'd need to use "yyDDD" if you've 5 digit Julian date.

```
DateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyDDD");
    try
    {
    Date date = dt.parse(longJulianDate);  //2018038
    String str = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {}
```